# Why is the output of recursive function 0?

Tags: c, recursion

Could somebody explain me why is this snippet of code returning 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int input)
{
    if (input > 0)
    {
        input--;
        return input * factorial(input);
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d", factorial(20));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll need `int64_t` to hold the value of 20!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the very last *inbound* iteration, in your code, when `input` is 1, executing

```
if (input > 0)
    {
    input--;  // see here, 1 goes to 0.....
    return input * factorial(input);
    }
```

essentially gives you

```
  return 0 * factorial (0);
```

which will eventually make the *whole* return value as 0.

Answer (score 3):

Lets simplify your question and find `factorial(2)`.

```
input=2;
```

after doing `(input--)`, `input == 1`

```
return 1*factorial(1)
```

Now, when `factorial(1)` is called.

```
input=1;
```

after doing `input--`, `input == 0`;

```
return 0*factorial(0)
```

So no matter what, factorial 0 returns zero -- which, multiplied by anything, becomes zero.

Answer (score 2):

In last iteration `input` becomes zero inside the `if` statement. Change your function to

```
int factorial(int input)
{
    if (input > 0)
    {
        return (input) * factorial(input-1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```